# SQL Server equivalent of Oracle 'byte'

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

SQL Server  equivalent of Oracle 'byte'

I'm looking for the SQL Server equivalent of the Oracle datatype `byte`. I searched for it in this documentation page (Data Type Mapping for Oracle Publishers), but I couldn't find it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/data-type-mapping-for-oracle-publishers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A byte (8 bits) is the same as a [tinyint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745(v=sql.105).aspx) in SQL Server